# Unable to install Keda on AKS with helm

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, kubectl, autoscaling, azure-aks

i am not able to install "Keda" with helm on AKS. Getting below error..

Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
Error: unable to convert to CRD type: unable to convert unstructured object to apiextensions.k8s.io/v1beta1, Kind=CustomResourceDefinition: cannot convert int64 to float64
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made a reproduction of your problem and that is the solution

You need to use

```
helm fetch kedacore/keda-edge --devel
```

To download keda files to your pc

Unzip it

```
tar -xvzf keda-edge-xxx.tgz
```

Then you need to change [hook](https://github.com/helm/helm/blob/master/docs/charts_hooks.md#hooks) in scaledobject-crd.yaml

```
nano keda-edge/templates/scaledobject-crd.yaml

"helm.sh/hook": crd-install need to be changed to "helm.sh/hook": pre-install
```

And install it will helm

```
helm install ./keda-edge --name keda


NAME:   keda
LAST DEPLOYED: Mon Sep 30 12:13:14 2019
NAMESPACE: default
STATUS: DEPLOYED

RESOURCES:
==> v1/ClusterRoleBinding
NAME                           AGE
hpa-controller-custom-metrics  1s
keda-keda-edge                 1s

==> v1/Deployment
NAME            READY  UP-TO-DATE  AVAILABLE  AGE
keda-keda-edge  0/1    1           0          1s

==> v1/Pod(related)
NAME                             READY  STATUS             RESTARTS  AGE
keda-keda-edge-6b55bf7674-j5kgc  0/1    ContainerCreating  0         0s

==> v1/Service
NAME            TYPE       CLUSTER-IP     EXTERNAL-IP  PORT(S)         AGE
keda-keda-edge  ClusterIP  10.110.59.143  <none>       443/TCP,80/TCP  1s

==> v1/ServiceAccount
NAME                 SECRETS  AGE
keda-serviceaccount  1        1s

==> v1beta1/APIService
NAME                             AGE
v1beta1.external.metrics.k8s.io  0s
```